# Encoding/decoding C Struct with components that are not encodable

Tags: c, objective-c, swift, struct, encoding

I have a struct defined in a C header like:

```
struct ComputeParameters {
    float scale;
    vector_float4 rgba;
}
```

It has to be defined in C and not in Swift for a reason, so I can't just add add the Coding protocol to it.

I need to be able store and restore the contents of instances of the struct - ideally from Swift, but I can make an Objective-C class to code it if necessary.

I tried to encode it with Obj-c:

```
NSValue *structValue = [NSValue value:&computeParams withObjCType:@encode(struct ComputeParameters)];
```

But I get this error:

> Encoding of 'struct ComputeParameters' type is incomplete because 'vector_float4' (aka 'simd_float4') component has unknown encoding

Other than encoding each and every component of the struct (there are like 3 dozen components), is there a better way?

Comment: SIMD conforms to Codable

Comment: Hmmm - I changed it to simd_float4 but get the same error and it appears that vector_float4  is the same type (evident in the error).

Comment: I don't know how to code in obj-c.  Can't you encode it using NSJSONSerialization? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization

Comment: creating a struct with vector_float4 means you use it with your metal implementation. Knowing this, isnt it easier to have an eye on where you feed your metal buffer? If this part is shaping the buffer out of objects then this object structure is what you may want to encode instead. encoding something that goes directly into metal buffers as is, is not a good idea. You get the most out of SecureCoding with NSCoder when you try to avoid creation of special data types.

Comment: do you want to encode into memory or in a file? And from that file decoding later on?

Comment: Correct; it is for Metal which is why the Struct can't be defined in Swift. I need to store and restore the entire state of my Metal app, so I need to store it to file and decode later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the actual bytes of the struct and then convert those bytes to `NSData` but that ends up being very low level and machine dependent. This is the one extreme of your options and may work and work well as long as you have the same underlying machine architecture. Then you can just as well code up the whole implementation in C and not use `NSData/NSCoding` at all.

If you use `NSCoding` then it comes with its own set of limitations as you see and you need to work with what it gives you. There are a few handy low level functions such as `encodeInt64` but then you still end up working with the individual members of the struct. This is the other extreme where you encode the individual struct members for each struct.

If you use Objective-C the middle ground can be to create a class for each struct along with code to get a struct from the class and to init a class from a struct. Then you need code to encode / decode each class. This will probably be a lot of work but if this integrates well into your solution I think is the better / more maintainable option.

The most direct way forward would be to use the low level `NSCoding` functions but you still end up mapping each and every struct member to some low level function but at least without a class to facilitate the encoding. Then you can e.g. create an identifier for each struct and use that when you decode to know what struct you need to create and decode into.